# jQuery Flot Charts: Auto bar width with dynamic items

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart, flot

My charts output dynamic data based on input filters. These can have 1 to 30 bars and they resize on screen resize/device. Just an example, currently where there's < 5 bars and the charts width is 1138px (max), then I have pretty big bars in width.

**Q.** How is this problem dealth with?

```
var options = {
          xaxis: { ticks: ticks},
          grid: { clickable: false, hoverable: true },
          series: { stack: true, bars: {show: true,align: 'center',barWidth: 0.5,lineWidth: 2,fillColor: {colors: [{opacity: 0.9}, {opacity: 0.9}]}} },
          legend: {container: ".widget-legend"}
       };
```

Comment: So, your problem is the variable bar width? Do you want a constant bar width in pixels?

Comment: as you see from my code, the bar width is always 0.5, even if I have only one bar, so how can I make the bar width dynamic?

Comment: That 0.5 is in x axis units and the width in pixels is variable depending on the width of the chart. I still don't understand what your problem is and what you want to achieve.

Comment: as I said, the number of bars in my chart is not constant, I could have 2 bars or 30 bars in one chart, based on filters,,, if I have 2 bars with 0.5 width in a 1138px chart, how would that look? I would have 2 big bars. The bars width needs somehow to be adjusted based on how many they are, and the chart width perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to give your bars the same pixel width whether there are 1 or 30 bars, you can calculate the value for `barWidth` from the width of the chart (in x axis units and pixels, correcting for axes and margins) using [cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication). A reasonable pixel width for up to 30 bars on 1100 pixels would be around 20 pixels per bar.

```
var chartWidthInPixels = 1100 * 0.95; // or $('#chart').width() * 0.95
var barWidthInPixels = 20; // or chartWidthInPixels / 50

var chartWidthInAxisUnits = (max(ticks) - min(ticks)) + 1; // this will be 1 for one bar
var barWidthInAxisUnits = barWidthInPixels * (chartWidthInAxisUnits / chartWidthInPixels);
```

For one bar with the above example values this gives around 0.019 for the `barWidth`. By variation of the constants in the formulas you can modify the calculation.